# Firefox pop up "This web page is being redirected to a new location" on every requestPromise ajax call- is there any way to avoid?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, firefox

I have a web app with a lot of AJAXing going on. In my original tests this was working fine, but in my testing today, Firefox (on both Mac & IE, on multiple computers), is giving a pop-up message "This web page is being redirected to a new location" for every single PUT & DELETE ajax call, which makes the page a totally unworkable mess. Interestingly, the pop-up does not occur on the GET calls.

The PUT & DELETE are both using an Angular Promise structure, while the GET uses a standard $.http call.

Here's the code of my GET, which does not trigger the pop-up:

```
 $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: $scope.faveURL
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data === "false") {
                    $scope.faveempty = true;
                    $scope.faveloading = false;
                } else {
                    $scope.favourites = data;
                    $scope.faveloading = false;
                }
            });
```

And here's the code of my PUT & DELETE, which both do trigger the pop-up:

```
if (food.favourite === true) {
                requestPromise = $http.put($scope.URL).then(function () {
                    $scope.favourites.push(food);
                    $scope.faveempty = false;
                    food.loading = "none";
                    change = $scope.favouriteChange(food);
                });

            } else if (food.favourite === false) {
                requestPromise =  $http({
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    url: $scope.URL
                }).then(function () {
                    $scope.favourites.splice($scope.favourites.indexOf(food), 1);
                    if ($scope.favourites.length < 1) {
                        $scope.faveempty = true;
                    }
                    food.loading = "none";
                    change = $scope.favouriteChange(food);
                });
            }
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem while using requestPromise for Ajax calls? Have you found any work-arounds?

---

UPDATE:

Checking the Network traffic, this is only occurring on AJAX calls which respond with a redirect. This is fine, no pop-up:

```
[15:09:58.742] GET http://redacted/api/ext/group/35/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 381ms]
```

This causes a pop-up:

```
[15:03:25.036] PUT http://redacted/api/ext/favorite/713 [HTTP/1.0 301 TYPO3 RealURL redirect 126ms]
```

So it's a problem with the way the Typo3 services are responding to the PUT & DELETE methods, and Firefox just so happens to have dialog warning for this.

Answer (score 0):

This may not directly help your case, but I was experiencing the same issue and it was due to me having the wrong request type. I am sure it may help others.

Bear in mind I am using jQuery.

Original code:

```
      $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: 'json',
        success: function(html) {
          return _this.ajaxLoadIn(html);
        },
        error: function(e) {
          return alert('Sorry, something went wrong, please try again');
        }
      });
```

Resolved code:

```
      $.ajax({
        url: link,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        success: function(html) {
          return _this.ajaxLoadIn(html);
        },
        error: function(e) {
          return alert('Sorry, something went wrong, please try again');
        }
      });
```

As you can see I was setting the wrong "type" parameter. It should have been GET or POST. Hopes this may shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely your backend doesn't accept URLs without trailing slashes (in case you are using them) and when it meets such a request it tries to redirect you to the right URL (with a trailing slash). This attempt to redirect you to the right URL results in the popup. So make sure you are using URLs with trailing slashes.

Regarding AngularJS RESTful infrustructure, `$resource` by default removes trailing slashes, but you can turn them on (starting from AngularJS 1.3.0). See more details in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a 10 year old question, but it was one of the first things to come up when searching for the phrase 'This page is being redirected to a new location'. In my case, the pop-up appears as I had changed the `network.http.prompt-temp-redirect` settings flag to `true` in Firefox's `about:config`. Setting is back to `false` stopped the pop-up.

Other people have reported success changing different values, you might as well check them all:

1. Enter `about:config` in the Firefox URL bar
2. Search for `network.http.prompt-temp-redirect`, ensure the value is set to `false`
3. Search for `network.http.redirection-limit`, ensure this is set to `20`
4. Search for `browser.meta_refresh_when_inactive.disabled`, ensure this is `false`